# Which library would you consider on linux for DEA (Data Encryption Algorithm)?

Tags: c++, linux, encryption, 3des

I need a 3DES encrypt/decrypt library for my project.
Do you know an implementation working on linux ?

Linux is the target platform, but I essantially compile/debug on Windows. Therefore it could be really appreciated if it could work on Windows, while not mandatory.

Comment: AFAIK 3DES isn't secure. FYI.

Comment: 3DES is secure *enough* for real-time data, where it's pointless to decrypt only one packet very late. Just bear in mind that keys should be rotated every minute or so...

Comment: 3DES is quite secure -- but it's a poor choice (at least in software) for fast encryption or decryption. A decent implementation of AES is substantially faster, and (generally believed to be) more secure.

Comment: Yes thank you for your comments, I wasn't aware of that. But the protocol is required by a remote server I need to connect to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenSSL is a very reputable, well tested open source security library.  It's available for *nix and Windows.  You can find it [here](http://openssl.org/)

Edit, can't find a simple example right now.  The API [documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/des.html#) is pretty good though.

There's a pre-compiled version for windows available for download from the openssl site.  Most package managers will have a pre-packaged version of OpenSSL for Linux boxes, so you shouldn't have to compile your own version.

Comment: I don't know how works openSSL. But the name Secured Socket Layer makes me believe every tcp segments will eventually be encrypted using with this protocol. Actually some part of my payload data must not be encrypted (for instance a specific header provided before the encrypted data). Is openSSL still applicable in this case?

Comment: @yves, yes.  You can use OpenSSL to encrypt a simple string.  You supply the string and tell it which encryption algorithm to use to encrypt it.  I'll edit my answer and supply a simple example in a few minutes

Answer (score 2):

Look for Eric Young's "libdes".
This library can be also used on Windows as well as on Linux.

Comment: If you are going to use libdes, you might as well use OpenSSL, which is based on SSLeay (which is more or less what libdes evolved into). Which would allow one to take advantage of the bugfixes and optimizations since EAY stopped working on the code in the late 90s, and the easy availability of packages for most platforms.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [botan](http://botan.randombit.net/news/) before and I really like it. It has an implementation of not only 3DES but a lot of others algorithm. It is C++ so their API is Object Oriented (I like this feature while other might disagree). It supports a lot of systems (Windows, Linux, FreeBSD, etc), a lot of processors (x86, x86-64, IA-64, PowerPC and so on) and compilers. It seems to have a very good performance. Finally its license allows commercial developments.

At least it's Worth to have a look ;-)

Answer (score 1):

you can compile libcrypto (openssl) for windows but I wouldn't recommend it:
http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/lib_crypto.html

Maybe NSS used by firefox would be useful?
http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/

Though I'd probably try something simple like:
http://www.lysator.liu.se/~nisse/nettle/nettle.html